# Reverse geocode using MKReverseGeocoder

Tags: google-maps, gps, reverse-geocoding, mkreversegeocoder

Google Terms says I can only use reverse geocoding in conjunction with a google map.

Is it ok if you first see the address in a uitableviewcell and then on a click see the location in a map (is this "in conjunction") ?

Tried two other free services but they don't find all locations as it seems.

**Edit**
I see in an answer that I need to clarify
The app should get the current gps location first using CLLocationManager and this location (latt,long) should be translated into a street/city name and displayed on the cell. 
Then, after getting a green/yellow light and a location description that fits the accuracy needs of the user, the user should normally click on the cell causing a map to load with stores of a certain company that are nearby. ("normally" because he could also hit another cell "Enter different location").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caveat emptor* I am not a lawyer and this advice is not a substitute for actual legal advice.

Assuming that when you click on the address, only then the address is reverse-geocoded, and the marker is displayed on the map, then yes, that would certainly count as "in conjunction" in my book.

Comment: Actually the app should get the current gps location using CLLocationManager and this location (latt,long) should be translated into a street/city name and displayed on the cell. 
Then, after getting a green/yellow light and a location description that fits the reality the user should normally click on the cell causing a map to load with stores of a certain company that are nearby. ("normally" because he could also hit another cell "Enter different location")